# Jquery / JS bind "paste" event handler to input textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, mouseevent, paste

Allright, SO i have an input box and I need to do things everytime it changes, I am having trouble doing it for mouse paste. Here is the code I have

```
$("#attack-navy"+unit.ID+"-number").bind('paste', function(){
            alert("paste detected");
            $("#attack-max-capacity").text(getMaxCapacity());
});
```

the getMaxCapacity() function return number entered * 30 for now;

Here is the scenario when

1: I paste 3, it will not change (i still see the alert)

2: Then when i paste 5, it will be 90(3 * 30)

3: Then if i paste 10 it will be 150(5 * 30), and so on.

I think its doing the handler before the paste actually occurs. Any ideas on what I can do? (.change will not work, it must happen as soon as u paste)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You should handle the `input` and `propertychange` events.
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SLaks/nt4SD/).

Comment: Would propertychange require me to leave focus?

Comment: I tried .bind('propertychange', function(){ ... doesnt seem to work

Comment: @Ave: `propertychange` is only for IE.  For other browser, you need `input`.

Comment: Oh wow, i never knew i had to do .bind('input', handler) THat is amazing, its weird I search so much but never heard of it before Thanks a lot!!

Comment: This answer would answer a lot of similar questions... :D

Comment: Can anyone tell me which minimum versions of different browsers will support this code?

Comment: @Cupidvogel: AFAIK, all of them. I'm not sure, though.

Comment: This stuff will not catch changes made by code: $("myInput").val("") - non of this events will be triggered.

Answer (score 3):

You're right. The paste event is firing before the value of the input changes. Try wrapping your handler in a timeout:

```
setTimeout(function() { $("#attack-max-capacity").text(getMaxCapacity()); }, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the bind event with .live and it should work, like this:

```
$("#attack-navy"+unit.ID+"-number").live('paste', function(){
            alert("paste detected");
            $("#attack-max-capacity").text(getMaxCapacity());
});
```